# Simple java spell checker / check if the word exists in the dictionary

Tags: java, loops, file, io

I am coding a simple spell checker. Just to check the spelling of the user text with that of a small dictionary file and compare them.

The 'dictionary.txt' file contains:

```
my
name
is
```

Here is my code to check and compare user text with the dictionary:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class SpellChecker
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner write = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a sentence and I will check your spelling/correct words :)");
        String sentence = write.nextLine();
        String[] splitSentence = sentence.split(" ");

        for(int i = 0; i < splitSentence.length; i++)
        {
            Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt"));

            while(read.hasNextLine())
            {
                String compare = read.nextLine();

                if(compare.equalsIgnoreCase(splitSentence[i]))
                {
                    System.out.println(splitSentence[i] + " : correct");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(splitSentence[i] + " : incorrect");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output I am getting.

```
Type a sentence and I will check your spelling/correct words :)
Heyo my name is Ivam
Heyo : incorrect
Heyo : incorrect
Heyo : incorrect
my : correct
my : incorrect
my : incorrect
name : incorrect
name : correct
name : incorrect
is : incorrect
is : incorrect
is : correct
Ivam : incorrect
Ivam : incorrect
Ivam : incorrect
```

Below is what I expected the output to be:

```
Type a sentence and I will check your spelling/correct words :)
Heyo my name is Ivam
Heyo : incorrect
my : correct
name : correct
is : correct
Ivam : incorrect
```

Comment: Does your dictionary file only have one word per line?

Comment: yes it does.

It has 3 lines 'my', 'name' and 'is'

Comment: It's because of your `while` loop logic. You are actually checking every line with the word and printing it as `correct`/`incorrect` for every line check.

Comment: Your dictionary may have a "space" or non printable control characters, such as carriage return or line feed. You should parse out the string from the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a `boolean` flag outside of `while` loop and add a check **outside of while** as below

```
...
boolean isCorrect = false;
while(read.hasNextLine()) {
  String compare = read.nextLine();
  if (compare.equalsIgnoreCase(splitSentence[i])) {
    isCorrect = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (isCorrect) {
  System.out.println(splitSentence[i] + " : correct");
} else {
  System.out.println(splitSentence[i] + " : incorrect");
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Set<String> dictionary = new HashSet<>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("dictionary.txt")));
    java.util.Scanner write = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a sentence and I will check your spelling/correct words :)");
    String sentence = write.nextLine();
    String[] splitSentence = sentence.split(" ");
    for (String word : splitSentence)
        if (dictionary.contains(word))
            System.out.println(word + " : correct");
        else
            System.out.println(word + " : incorrect");
}
```

output

```
Type a sentence and I will check your spelling/correct words :)
Heyo my name is Ivam
Heyo : incorrect
my : correct
name : correct
is : correct
Ivam : incorrect
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I see it is that the while loop will run compare the specific word to each word in the dictionary, therefore returning multiple results. One solution would be to, if the word is correctly found, then print out to the console that it is correct, otherwise, if and only if it has run through all of the dictionary and found no matches, then print out that it is incorrect.

In this case its solved by having the string set as default for incorrect and only change to correct if it doesnt find the match. Then at the end of the loop it just prints the latest result string. I also initialized the variables outside the loop so its not done every single time as it is unnecessary.

Here is how the solution could work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class SpellChecker
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner write = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a sentence and I will check your spelling/correct words :)");
        String sentence = write.nextLine();
        String[] splitSentence = sentence.split(" ");

        
        String result = null;
        String compare = null;
        Scanner read = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < splitSentence.length; i++)
        {
            read = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt"));

            result = "incorrect";
            
            while(read.hasNextLine())
            {
                compare = read.nextLine();

                if(compare.equalsIgnoreCase(splitSentence[i]))
                {
                    result = "correct";
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            
            System.out.println(splitSentence[i] + " : " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the below code and it is working as expected. For each word whenever you find a word in dictionary you can set a flag to true and break the loop. If you dont find a word at the end you can check for this flag and print it is incorrect.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner write = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a sentence and I will check your spelling/correct words :)");
        String sentence = write.nextLine();
        String[] splitSentence = sentence.split(" ");
        
        for(int i = 0; i < splitSentence.length; i++)
        {
            Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt"));
            boolean found = false;
            while(read.hasNextLine())
            {
                String compare = read.nextLine();

                if(compare.equalsIgnoreCase(splitSentence[i]))
                {
                    System.out.println(splitSentence[i] + " : correct");
                    found=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!found)
               System.out.println(splitSentence[i] + " : incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```